# How to show only products that are allowed to logged in user in Magento?

Tags: magento

In our current implementation of Magento, situation is as follows:

There are two types of products (items) under various categories. 
1. Allowed to all 
2. Allowed to specific logged in user (customer)

e.g. Let us assume that there are 100 items (under different categories) which are allowed to be shown to all logged in or not logged in users

Now there are 10 items which are allowed to be seen only by Customer A (Set A)
5 Items which are allowed to be seen only by Customer B. (Set B)

So when Customer A logs in, he/she will see all items that are allowed to all + Items from Set A but not from Set B.

When Customer B logs in, he/she will all items that are allowed to all + Items from Set B but not from Set A.

How can I achieve this result in Magento? Should I handle it in MySQL or within Magento modules?

Please suggest,

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create Three attributes for each product.
allowedgroupA, allowedGroupB and allowedAll.

Now for products only for group B check allowedGroupB and for other two attributes done check.

Same for for products only for group A check allowedGroupA and for other two attributes done check.

products for all groups will have allowedAll as checked.

Now in your block code apply appropriate filter depending on customer logged in group.

Additional Comments:
Additionally if you have some product only for specific group or for all then just have one attributes.
allowedGroupId.
if allowedGroupId is set then its only for that specific customer group if its 0 then its for all customers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there will be 100s of group as there are 100s of customers and each one will have similar rule.

Comment: other way is associate specific category to specific group and modify your code to handle.